# How to highlight selected item in listView with a large list of items?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom ListView in a tablet app where there's a ListView on the left and detailed fragment on the right, when you select an Item on the left from the listView I want it to be highlighted and stay highlighted (I did this part) but when I scroll down to the bottom of the list and back and due to **The recycling of views**  it forgets the highlighting, how can I do it in a different way?

Here's the code I used in the adapter for the ListView:

```
protected LinearLayout selectedItem;
protected LinearLayout selectedItemPosition = -1;
.
.
.
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3; // I have 3 types of list Items, this part is working fine..
}
public int getItemViewType(int pos) {
    // This part works fine too
}
.
.
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder;
.
.
.
if (selectedItemPosition == pos) {
    holder.listItem.setSelected(true);
}

final LinearLayout listItem = holder.listItem;      

holder.listItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (clickCallback != null) {                    
            if (activateOnClick) {
                if (selectedItemPosition > -1) {
                    selectedItem.setSelected(false);
                }
                selectedItemPosition = pos;
                listItem.setSelected(true);
                selectedItem = listItem;
            }
            clickCallback.callback(NewsItems.get(pos));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create custom selector for listview item - listview_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yourColor" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/yourColor" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/yourColor" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/yourColor" />
</selector>
```

And then, use

```
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.listview_selector);
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with drawable or hos selection looks like, the problem is that View Recycling makes it forget the selection